# Having to pass a lot of information about using inheritance, am I using it correctly?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In a turn-based combat game, all actions that characters can perform inherit from this class. It started off looking like this:

```
using ActionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Action>;
class Action {
public:
Action(Entity actor, std::uint32_t time) { ... }
virtual ActionPtr execute() = 0;
...
std::uint32_t time; // time that the action will occur. For e.g 10 if it occurs in tick 10 of combat
    Entity actor; // the character performing the action
    };
```

Upon entering combat, everyone gets a DecideAction that allows characters to decide what to do (either bring up menus for the player, or the AI choosing actions).
The combat system's maintains a timeline of actions; sorted by the time that actions should occur and the speed of actors to break ties. Its update function does something like this:

```
sortTimeline();
ActionPtr followUpAction = timeline.front()->execute();
timeline.removeFront();
timeline.push_back(followUpAction);
```

For example, the AiDecideAction executing returns the follow-up action (i.e what that entity chose to do). An attack action's execution would return a decide action set to happen after attack-dependent cooldowns. These actions get added and processed in the next tick.

Since actions can create other actions, I'm finding that I have to push all the possible info that actions may require to execute to the Action class, the root of the inheritance hierarchy. This is so that it can properly construct follow-up actions. For e.g

```
AttackAction::execute() {
...
return ActionPtr(new AiDecide(actor, nextActionTime, allies, enemies);
 // allow this entity to decide what to do after attacking
}
```

The attack action needs access to allies and enemies just to supply it to constructors; so I ended up modifying the constructor of Action to take in all possible info that derived actions may require to try solving this problem.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm wondering if inheritance is the right way to model this problem. I've had to modify all actions several times so that information required for constructing other actions is present, which isn't ideal.